# elasticsearch- comparing different indexed documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and not quite sure how to use it prooperly.
I have the follwing problem. I want to index different documents and
check if they contain certain search terms. There are more than a
million texts and some ten thousands search terms.

My idea was to index both, the texs and the serach terms so I have
something like that:
`http://localhost:9200/text/type/id 
http://localhost:9200/searchterm/type/id`

I didn't find any solution how to join those two indexes. So I suppose
my thought went into a wrong direction.

Can anyone help me with that?  If you need more information I will try
to give it to you but currently am at the very beginning so there is
not so much more to it. I would really appreciate some help, tank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use terms lookup mechanism for this.

in the document 'http://www.HOSTNAME:9200/searchterm/type/id' , you can create a field called 'searchTerms' and store the search terms in this.

Something like

```
searchterm/type/id
  {
    "searchTerms" : [ "search" , "me" , "and" , "this" , "term" , "Also" ]
  }
```

Once this is done , you can refer to this document in your filtered query.

```
curl -XGET www.HOSTNAME:9200/text/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "user" : {
            "index" : "searchterm",
            "type" : "type",
            "id" : "id",
            "path" : "searchTerms"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

This way , you can refer to terms in another document for your filtering.

LINK - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html#_terms_lookup_mechanism

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This was the start I baldy needed. I tried it and it worked fine. I guess I can add stuff like alternative spellings to the searchTerms array?

Comment: Yup  , that will just work fine. But a better approach would be to use synonym analyzers to do this.

Comment: True but for my specific case (lots of technical terms and paraphrases) such an analyzer wouldn't distribute all the needed synonyms by default. Maybe if I did some additions.. maybe I'll try that at a later date.

For my actual problem i there a possibility to iterate over all of the search terms with just one request or do I have to make several tens of thousands requests per text?